# How to detect design time in aspx

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Basically I would like to modify my CSS file under design time.  And the easiest way I can think of to do it is to just comment out a block of CSS/JS code in my Master ASPX page.  How do I do this?  Is there anyway to detect design time in ASP.NET?

Comment: how exactly do you want to modify the CSS? typically you have static style sheets that are dynamically loaded.

Comment: Use jQuery to change CSS class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick way to detect is:

```
if (HttpContext.Current == null)
// You're in design mode
```

or

```
  if (this.Site != null && this.Site.DesignMode == true)
  {
    // Design Mode
 }
 else
 {
    // Run-time
  }
```

Comment: What about in the actual ASPX page?  You know, within the <HTML> </HTML> tag.